# Java: Object loop stuck after first entry

Tags: java, for-loop

So I have this little piece of code:
`System.out.println("Size: " + mounts.keySet().size());
for (JHttpPath entry : mounts.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Got one: " + entry.getPath());
    if (entry.getDomain().equalsIgnoreCase(path.getDomain()) && entry.getPath().equalsIgnoreCase(path.getPath())) {
        System.out.println("WIN! " + entry.getPath());
        return mounts.get(entry);
    }
}`

And this is the output:
`Size: 4
Got one: /host`
But it should be:
`Size: 4
Got one: /host
Got one: /cookie
Got one: /
Got one: /`

Any idea on what is blocking the statement :P

Comment: Does it hang or does it complete with that result?

Comment: `entry.getDomain()`, `path.getDomain()`, `entry.getPath()`, or `path.getPath()` is blocking. Use the debugger, Luke!

Comment: The simplest thing is to launch it in debug mode in Eclipse (or something similar for some other IDE) and when it hangs, you suspend the VM and see where your threads are.

Comment: @JamesMontagne It stucks :/ It is obvious that it doesn't continue the thread as it doesn't return something where it's waiting for. I even tested it and the thread gets stuck :(

Comment: I certainly hope your "But it should be" part is just an example, as a `Set` (which `Map`'s [keySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) returns) can't have duplicate elements.

Comment: @Powerlord If you look into the code you can see it's not duplicated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as this is commercial software I can't provide one of the classes.
This may seem very like a beginner question but it is actually very odd.
The problem: The String where I used .equals(IgnoresCase) was defined as NULL, this resulted in an exception which is ignored on purpose by my software.
My bad, thanks for all input.

**Solution code:**
`(entry.getDomain() == null || path.getDomain() == null || entry.getDomain().equalsIgnoreCase(path.getDomain()))`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that one of your methods executed after the Got one line is printed is entering into an endless loop. `GetDomain()` from the looks of it.

Maybe if we knew a bit more about `JHttpPath` ?  I assume it's a custom class, as Google only turns up this very question when Googling `JHttpPath`.

Comment: It is likely to be `getDomain()` that does the infinite loop (or maybe recursion), and not `getPath()`, otherwise there'd be no output at all.